# How to append to a drowdownlist with Jquery inside a ASP.NET Datagrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, xml

The following function in my 'aspx' page is working, but the 'dropdown' inside the GridControl is getting copied... from the original row.  It is not being changed from the appended rows.  You can see the line I have attempted, but I'm not sure what to put there.  I have also posted the Grid-Control itself.  I don't think you need the webmethod, nor any code-behind here.  A scripting wiz should be able to just tell me what I need I believe.
FYI... This is using Load-On-Demand from aspsnippits dot com -- at least a concept there-of.

```
 //Function to receive XML response append rows to GridView
function OnSuccess(response) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
    pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());
    var customers = xml.find("Customers");
    $("[id$=GridView_MyCustomers] .loader").remove();
    customers.each(function () {
        var customer = $(this);
        var row = $("[id$=GridView_MyCustomers] tr").eq(0).clone(true);
        $(".ID", row).html(customer.find("id").text());
        $(".Name", row).html(customer.find("customername").text());
        $(".company", row).html(customer.find("company").text());
        $(".email", row).html(customer.find("email").text());
        $(".phone", row).html(customer.find("phone").text());
        $(".address", row).html(customer.find("customeraddress").text());

        $(".projeng", row).val(customer.find("usproengineer").text()).change(); //does not work

        $(".regdate", row).html(customer.find("registrationdate").text());
        $(".payterms", row).html(customer.find("paymentterms").text());
        $(".country", row).html(customer.find("country").text());
        $("[id$=GridView_MyCustomers]").append(row);
    });

    //Hide Loader
    $("#loader").hide();
}

 <%--My Customers«e¥x¬É­±--%>
 <div id="customers" runat="server" style="padding-left:10px"> 
     <h2>My Customers</h2>
     <img src="Images/raise.png" alt="" id="jqshow_8" />
     <img src="Images/drop.png" alt="" id="jqhide_8" />
     <asp:LinkButton ID="jqlbtn_8" runat="server" OnClick="lbtn_MyCustomers_Click" CssClass="linkbutton-customer"
         >My Customers</asp:LinkButton>            
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <span id="tag_8">
        <asp:Button ID="export_customer" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="25px"
            Text="Export Customer List" onclick="export_customer_Click" />
     </span>
     <input id="hidden_8" type="hidden" runat="server" value="0" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <asp:Button ID="btPrev" runat="server" Text="&lt;-" />
     <asp:Button ID="btNext" runat="server" Text="-&gt;" onclick="btNext_Click" />
     <div id="div_8">
     <div id="dvGrid" style="max-height:500px; width:auto; overflow-y:auto">
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView_MyCustomers" runat="server" AllowSorting="true"  OnSorting="Customer_Sorting"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="GridViewStyle" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView_MyCustomers_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="usproengineer" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_MyCustomers_PageIndexChanging"
        onrowdeleting="lbtn_CustomerDelete" 
              PageSize="500" >        
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="id" ItemStyle-CssClass="ID" />       
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Contact" DataField="customername"  SortExpression="customername" ItemStyle-CssClass="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Company" DataField="company"  SortExpression="company" ItemStyle-CssClass="company" />
        <asp:templateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" ItemStyle-CssClass="email">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_customeremail" runat="server" OnClick="lbtn_customeremail_Click" Text='<%#Eval("email") %>' 
                   ></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:templateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Phone" DataField="phone" ItemStyle-CssClass="phone"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="customeraddress" ItemStyle-CssClass="address"
              ItemStyle-Width="150px" >
            <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:templateField HeaderText="US Project Manager" ItemStyle-CssClass="projeng">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_customerproeng" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="customerproeng_SelectedIndexChanged"
                     AutoPostBack="true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:templateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Registration Date" DataField="registrationdate" ItemStyle-CssClass="regdate"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Note" DataField="paymentterms" ItemStyle-CssClass="payterms"
              ItemStyle-Width="150px" >
                <ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_customerdelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="{if(confirm('Are you sure to delete this customer?')){ return true;}return false;}" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" HeaderText="?ÂÃªºcountry" ItemStyle-CssClass="country">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_country" ReadOnly="True" Text='<%#Eval("country") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>        
    <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
    <FooterStyle CssClass="FooterStyle" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
    <EditRowStyle CssClass="EditRowStyle" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRowStyle" />
 </asp:GridView>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I should add: In my debugging and debugging.  I can see the value change in the DOM, and it seems that row's cell does have the correct value, that gets appended into the grid.  But it still does not show on the screen, and still says the wrong person selected in the drop down in the end.

Comment: Your class `$(".projeng", ...)` isn't on the dropdownlist, it's on the template. Try moving the class to the ddl first. Then you want to do what? Change the selected item in the ddl?

Comment: That was it...However, I can get this to work: $(".projeng", row).val('35');, but not select by text.  Unless there is a property I'm not seeing.

Comment: Nevermind I added the ID to the datastream and it works.
If you would like, you (wazz) can submit as the answer below.

Comment: Thanks. Answer added, plus some extra if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class $(".projeng", ...) isn't on the dropdownlist, it's on the template. Try moving the class to the ddl first.

To select a dropdown item by text you can try this:

```
$("#ddl_customerproeng option").filter(function() {
    return ($(this).text() == "the text"); // does current option's text = "the text"?
}).prop("selected", true); // select the option.
```